# How to trigger slot from another header file

Tags: qt5, signals-slots

```
    SettingDialog *s = new SettingDialog();
QObject::connect(SettingsLabelBtn,SettingsLabelBtn->clicked(),s,s->changeSettings());
```

I have mainwindow.h and settingdialog.h. I want to when click SettingLabelBtn(it is QPushButton object) this event trigger to slots from settingdialog.h.

mainwindow class derived from QMainWindow also it has Q_Object macro
settingdialog class derived from QDialog aslo it has Q_Object macro

My error is no matching member function for call to 'connect'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `connect` syntax is wrong -- you're calling the member functions rather than passing their respective addresses.  Try...

```
QObject::connect(SettingsLabelBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, s, &SettingDialog::changeSettings);
```

Also see the [documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) regarding the new signal/slot syntax.

Comment: Heyy thank you :) I found answer and i came for tell my error reason however you were quick :))